# Custom Post Type and data from custom table

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am new in wordpress dev. 
So I have a custom table in my database
Now I want to retrive all the information from this table and present it in a wordpress Custom Post type

any ideas how to approach this issue?

Thank you

Comment: There is a site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Plugin-based approach: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

Comment: please explain a bit more.